# Wordpress show recent post blogs in static page

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

In  WordPress I am displaying a static front page with the `Front page displays` setting in the `Reading` panel. This is working good but I would like to show a list of recent blog posts into this static page.I am not sure what will be the best method to show the recent blog posts in this static page. So can someone please guide me to show the recent blogs in the static page? Any help and suggestions will be appreciable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this piece of code where you want to show the blog content

```
<div class="blog-post-wrap">
  <?php
  $args = array( 'numberposts' => '4' );
  $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );
  foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){?>
    <div class="blog"><?php echo substr($recent["post_content"], 0 , 150); ?>
      <span class="link"><?php echo '<a href="' . get_permalink($recent["ID"]) . '" title="Reaed More '.$recent["post_title"].'" >' .   'Read More'.'</a> '; ?></span>
    </blog>
  <?php } ?>
</div>
```

I have used `<?php echo substr($recent["post_content"], 0 , 150); ?>` piece of code to show limited characters on the page. You can change that as your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use an iframe to wrap your query and place the iframe on any html or php page without having to touch your current page code.... See detail explanation on this link: http://allnigeriansinspain.com/blog/show-wordpress-post-on-static-html-page/